# Git hook for merge conflicts

Tags: git, hook, githooks

Is there a git hook I can use for merge conflicts? After a failed `git merge`, it would be great to be able to write a script that opens all files with conflicts in `$EDITOR`. Unfortunately the `post-merge` hook doesn't run if there are conflicts and from what I've seen in the `githooks` man page, there are no other applicable hooks.

I'm wondering if I've missed something, or if there are other alternatives short of aliasing 'git merge' to a function or something like that.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You could use a custom mergetool that is just an editor rather than a true three way mergetool and run `git mergetool` when you you get conflicts.

Comment: Good suggestion. I didn't consider this because I really don't like any of the merge tools and have found fixing my conflicts directly in an editor better. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817370/using-ediff-as-git-mergetool) as a possible solution and I think customizing the [mergetool](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-mergetool.html) is definitely the way to go. The question is now, what to do with my question? Should I click "Answer Your Question" at the bottom of the page, or do nothing?

Comment: Question not directly answered. Clarification may help.

Of the events git supports for hooking, including (based on default `.git/hook/*.sample` files):

 1. `post-checkout`
 2. `post-commit`
 3. `post-merge`
 4. `post-receive`
 5. `post-update`
 6. `pre-applypatch`
 7. `pre-commit`
 8. `pre-push`
 9. `pre-rebase`

... does one or more apply during a merge conflict?

As git forces `root` ownership and limited permissions during merge conflicts, ordinary users cannot resolve merge conflicts. A merge conflict hook would allow for setting usable ownership, permissions.

Comment: I never run git as root and should have run into permission issues if what you say is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Charles Bailey, the best way to do this is by customizing the mergetool. Using [this guide](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), I came up with this simple way to have merge conflicts opened in my editor:

```
[merge]
  tool = emacs
[mergetool "emacs"]
  cmd = $editor \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Since Charles Bailey never answered how I should give him credit for this, I hope this is an appropriate way to finally close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there maybe two ways, as mentioned you by floose you could edit your mergetool or perhaps you could create another alias using:

```
for i in $(git ls-files -u | cut -f 2 | sort -u); do $EDITOR $i; done
```