# Clojure syntax aware git merge mode?

Tags: git, clojure

Git have syntax aware merge strategies. According to [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html), it has customized strategies intuitively named `ada`, `bibtex`, `cpp`, `csharp`, `fortran`, `html`, `java`, `matlab`, `objc`, `pascal`, `perl`, `php`, `python`, `ruby` and `tex`.

Are there any "third party" git merge strategies aware of Clojure syntax (or at least more lispy syntax)? Something like [codeq](https://github.com/Datomic/codeq#codeq) but for git?

Comment: Can you add a specific example of how the default merge strategy fails for Clojure code, and an example of how it should work (possibly from codeq)? Git supports a number of merge strategies and `diff` algorithms already; maybe one of those will work for you.

Comment: It means merging by line and not by S-expression, `(map inc list)` and `(map (fn[a] ...) list)` are not properly merged and treated as conflict.

Comment: updated question with a list* of git merge strategies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible [to use an external tool](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) for merging.

So even if it's not perfect, you can try [using ediff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817370/using-ediff-as-git-mergetool) for Clojure files as a merge tool.

You can also try [merging within a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587626/git-merging-within-a-line) breaking on `(`, `[`, `{`.