# Ediff as git difftool

Tags: git, emacs, emacs-ediff

I'm trying to use emacs ediff as a git difftool.

I have followed some of the configurations proposed here:
[Using ediff as git mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817370/using-ediff-as-git-mergetool)

When it comes to comparing between different git revisions of a certain file, I have not problem at all: ediff works well and the differences between both versions are depicted properly.

However, I'm having problems when I try to run git difftool to compare the current directory version of a file with a certain git revision.
For some files, I'm getting the following error:

> `apply: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil`

It is weird, because this error only comes for certain files, not all of them.

I have experimented with several files, and I think that the rule of thumb is as follows:
- If the file to be compared is not placed in the git root directory, then it fails.
- Otherwise, ediff shows the differences between the current version of the file and the specified revision without any problem.

I have tried with some of the configurations explained in the link I referred to above. All of them give me the same result: git difftool fails when comparing the current directory version of a non-root git file with a certain git revision.

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Thanks a lot.
-Bob

Comment: Well, yes, I know meld, but I prefer ediff since it is part of my workflow. I also use magit inside emacs, and it works perfectly. But there are sometimes when I want to launch a diff immediately, without getting into magit, and that is why I need ediff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git knows about a number of standard diff/merge tools, including ediff/emerge. Try

```
git config --global diff.tool ediff
```

and invoke it with

```
git difftool --tool=ediffclient master -- <file>
```

or similar. `ediffclient` will use emacsclient and not start a new emacs, which I prefer but YMMV.

EDIT (in response to a comment): If git complains about edifftool, try adding the following to your global git config file (`$HOME/.gitconfig`):

```
[difftool "ediff"]
          cmd = emacs --eval \"(ediff-files \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\")\"
[difftool "ediffclient"]
          cmd = emacsclient --eval \"(ediff-files \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\")\"
```

I was under the impression that these settings are part of the installation but maybe I'm wrong (or maybe that changed in a more recent version of git). I'll try to dig a little deeper when I find some time.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried what you said and it works fine. Regards

Comment: Sorry about that. I completely forgot it... Thanks

Comment: `Unknown merge tool ediffclient
fatal: external diff died, stopping`

Comment: @Christoph90: Please let me know if the edit helps - thanks!

Comment: Yes, including these lines in `.gitconfig` made it work for me. The config previously only had my name and E-Mail and ediff as diff tool set. Thanks